# Select Item From City Not Fill Items In District Drop Down When Create

Tags: linq

I have 4 table

Country table

Id  primarykey increment identity

Countryname

City table

Id primary key increment identity

Cityname

CountryId forignkey

Ditrict  table

Id primarykey increment identity

Districtname

CityId  forignkey

Employee table

Id  primary key increment identity

fname

sname

salary

Bonus

districtid forignkey

Relation not have any problem and relation in sql server database is good

when select items from country it fill city drop down list without any problem

but when i select item from city it not fill items in district why

something wrong in my code i do as following
my controller employee as following

Employee Controller

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{

// GET: Employee
mytaskdbEntities db = new mytaskdbEntities();
public ActionResult Index()
{
return View(db.Employees.ToList());
}
public ActionResult Create()
{
ViewBag.CountryList = new SelectList(db.Countries.ToList(), "Id","Countryname");

return View();
}
public JsonResult getcitybyid(int id)
{
db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
return Json(db.Cities.Where(a =>a.CountryId == id), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
public JsonResult getdistrictbyid(int id)
{
db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
return Json(db.Districts.Where(a => a.CityId == id), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
}
}
```

my Employee view is

```
@model LinqProject.Models.Employee
@{
Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Create</title>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
$("#CountryList").change(function () {
$("#citylist").empty();
// alert("error");
var x = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
url: "/Employee/getcitybyid",
data: { id: x },
success:function(res)
{
$.each(res, function (i, e) {
$("#citylist").append("<option value='"+e.id+"'>"+e.Cityname+"<option>")

});
}
});


});
$("#citylist").change(function () {
$("#districtlist").empty();
var y = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
url: "/Employee/getdistrictbyid",
data: { id: y },
success: function (res) {
$.each(res, function (i, e) {
$("#districtlist").append("<option value='" + e.id + "'>" + e.Districtname + "<option>")

});
}
});


});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div> 
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<div>
FirstName:@Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.fname)

</div>
<div>
LastName:@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.sname)

</div>
<div>
Salary:@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Salary)

</div>
<div>
Bonus:@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Bonus)

</div>
<div>
Bonus:@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Active)

</div>
<div>
CountryName:@Html.DropDownList("CountryList")

</div>
<div>
CityName:<select id="citylist" name="CityId"></select>
</div>
<div>
District:<select id="districtlist" name="districtId"></select>
</div>
<input type="submit" />
}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should step through [The debugger](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-A-Beginn)  Doing so will help you narrow down your problem.  Make sure `db.Districts.Where(a => a.CityId == id)` gets called, makes sure it returns results.  check what `id` is, and make sure that in you database, there are districts who's `CityId` is equal to `id`.  Try to understand why your code as a whole should work and see if you can figure out which part isn't doing what it's supposed to do

Comment: Once you've done that, and if you've determined that your problem is not on your server, then from your browser, press `F12`  That will bring up your web development tools, and there you can debug your javascript, inspect your html, and track your ajax requests.

Comment: I put break point in line db.Districts.Where(a => a.CityId == id) it not have any value after i select value in runtime

Comment: What has no value, and what do you mean by no value?  Does `id` have a value, is it null, is it an empty list, etc

Comment: yes empty list show without any exception or error

Comment: although database have values and relations is true and after break to  db.Districts.Where(a => a.CityId == id) this line then run it not give me any value to id and it it give me int id

Comment: Are you saying that `id` is equal to `0`?

Comment: when i go to id and stop cursor it give me(parameter)int id although i select value from drop down list city and when stop cursor in CityId it give me int?District.CityId{get;set;}